Delphi Jedi: HID connection
I need to connect to a device with Jedi for Delphi.
But I am new to HID and serial ports.
I sadly don't even know where I should start.
Well I tried to look it up and I got there:
https://wiki.delphi-jedi.org/wiki/Category:JvHidControllerClass.pas_Classes
But sadly the documentation of all the components that I probably need doesn't tell me much.
I appretiate your help.

When the device communicates through a serial port, you don't need a HID but a serial port component

Welcome to Stack Overflow - listing all questions tagged delphi and hid or the same matches reduced to those also containing TjvHidDevice.

@DelphiCoder Yeah thanks, I know. I am generally new to Ports, com port and hid but I need help for hid.

The USB serial device should have a driver which will then expose a serial port device you can use.  You only need to care about the serial device provided by the driver.
